# Validating a textbox with watermark

Tags: jquery, asp-classic

I've looked at posts that ask how to do this, but I'm new to JQuery so I may be missing something that would help with how my form is set up.

I have a classic asp page with a search box that has a watermark "Employee Last Name" in the text box.  I want to validate this field as required.  The watermark is working fine, and the validation works fine, but won't validate properly if the watermark is there.  I guess it's seeing the watermakr as an entered value?

Any tips on how I can keep my watermark and still validate this field?  Here's the code I'm using:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//Form watermarks
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.watermarked_title').watermark('watermark');
    });
    </script>


    <script>
//Validation
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        // binds form submission and fields to the validation engine                    
        jQuery("#SearchForm").validationEngine();
    });

    </script>
```

Form code:

```
<form action="EmpSearch.asp" method="Post" id="SearchForm">                         
    <input name="SearchLN" id="SearchLN" type="text" size="22" class="validate[required] searchBox watermarked_title" title="Employee Last Name" >&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <input type="submit" class="button" Value="Search">                     
</form>
```

Comment: And what's your validation code? That's likely to be the most important part. @gdoron: think `placeholder`, I imagine.

Comment: watermark is text one input that is faint before user enter text

Comment: @DavidThomas. Found it, thanks. See my answer below...

Comment: It´s nearly impossible to give you proper advise without knowing how you are doing the validation, and even what´s the watermark code (looks like a jQuery plugin, I´ve never heard of it).  
If you can live without this "watermark" (call it placeholder) on IE, you can go with [native HTML5 placeholders](http://www.w3schools.com/html5/att_input_placeholder.asp)

Comment: Sorry I forgot to include the validation code.  I'm not sure if I can include it in the comment box, but it's validation I found from here: https://github.com/posabsolute/jQuery-Validation-Engine/blob/master/js/jquery.validationEngine.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The watermark value should be cleared before submit:

> Form submission - The plugin automatically cleans up all watermarks prior to form submission, so you should never need to manually remove watermarks before submit.

If you use it right...:

> **Using the Watermark and Validate plugins on the same elements**
>
> If you find that your form validation is failing because the watermarks are
> not being cleared before validation occurs, then you need to adjust
> the order in which you set up the watermarks and validation.
>
> The proper order is to always set up watermarks before anything else
> -- especially before validation. That's because jQuery carefully controls the order of events during form submission, and calls them in
> the order they were set up. If you set up validation first, then the
> form will be validated before the watermarks are cleared.
>
> Setting up watermarks and validation in the proper order is as simple
> as placing the lines of code in the correct order, like in the
> following example:

```
$('#myElement').watermark('Required');
$('#myForm').validate();
```

[source](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-watermark/)

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I'm still learning all this, so I didn't realize that.  However, isn't this the order I had it in already in the proper order?

Comment: @Cineno28. I don't know is you problem cuz I can't debug it for you. Read this piece of docs: _"Form submission - The plugin automatically cleans up all watermarks prior to form submission, so you should never need to manually remove watermarks before submit."_

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I though I had their order right but made some edits and now it's working.  This was definitely the answer.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to handle the form's submit event and clear out any fields with *placeholders* (don't call them watermarks... that's for images).

```
$('#myform').submit(function(){
    $('.placeholder').each(function(){
        var $placeholder = $(this);
        if ($placeholder.val() == $placeholder.attr('title')) {
            $placeholder.val('');
        }
    });
});
```

This assumes that you give fields with these placeholders a "placeholder" class, and that you're using the `title` attribute of the field to store the placeholder text (fairly common). You'll need to modify it slightly if that's not the case.

Comment: See my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9673295/601179), `watermark` is a plugin he's using.

Comment: Yeah, I've heard of it, and I'd like to smack the guy who wrote that plugin for calling it a "watermark".

Comment: @Chris Pratt Thanks Chris, I'll try this out.  Yeah I'm using a plugin I found so I didn't know placeholder was the proper term.  Thanks for letting me know

Comment: Couldn't find in the official plugin website where does he live. Sorry. But I do know he's in the lottery business...